# Trouble creating a PHP string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database driven website. There is a basic template that is the format for each page.
There are various parts that need to change for each different page.
One line for an example is this.

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://mywebsite.com/details.php?id=1" />
```

I changed the line code to this and stills it works fine and does exactly what I wanted it to do.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo "$record->canonical";?>" />
```

The problem I am having is, when the cell is empty I am printing this line which is not need if the quotes are blank. How can I remove this line when the cell in my database is empty?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="" />
```

Comment: could you give more detail about $record->canonical can you share the page code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php if ($record->canonical != ""): ?>
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $record->canonical ?>" />
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
echo($record->canonical != "" ? $record->canonical : '');
?>
```

Which is the same as if $record->canonical is not "" (after the ?-sign) echo it, otherwise (after the :-sign) echo nothing ( '' ).